# How to split 10% of data set to “control” and 90% to “test” for each group in MS SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Context:**
I have a table which has RetailerCode, CustomerID,Segment like below

```
RetailerCode    CID        Segment
A6005         13SVC15       High
A6005         19VDE1F       Low
A6005         1B3BD1F       Medium
A6005         1B3HB48       Medium
A6005         1B3HB49       Low
A9006         1B3HB40       High
A9006         1B3HB41       High
A9006         1B3HB43       Low
A9006         1B3HB46       Medium
```

Here, I would like to divide the data set in to control and test as below,
For each RetailerCode, I have set of customers with each customer tagged to a segment. I need to divide in such a way that

> For each retailer
>
> - 10% of their High customers to control and remaining 90% of their high customers to test.
> - 10% of their Medium customers to control and remaining 90% of their Medium customers to test.
> - 10% of their Low customers to control and remaining 90% of their Low customers to test.

I tried below code and I know its wrong.

```
select RetailerCode, CID,Segment 
(case when row_number() over (order by newid()) <= (select 0.1* count(*) from Table)
             then 'control'
             else 'test'
        end) as group
from Table
group by RetailerCode, CID,Segment
Order by RetailerCode
```

Can someone please help me with it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem pretty close:

```
select RetailerCode, CID,Segment 
       (case when row_number() over (partition by segment order by newid()) <=
                  0.1 * count(*) over (partition by segment) 
             then 'control'
             else 'test'
        end) as group
from Table
Order by RetailerCode;
```

I don't see why a `group by` is needed.

Comment: Your Code is totally what I was expecting but can you tell me this. You have not used retailercode anywhere apart from order by but it still calculates for each retailer code and it splits perfectly. Can you explain that? you have used partition by segment which is great but it should also based on retailer code, right?

Comment: @dnarb . . . Actually, that would be from the laws of statistics.  The query would be better to have `RetailerCode` in the `partition by` as well as `segment`.  Does that also work for you?

Comment: I just did a QA and it looks like segment level split is not correct. I will post a separate detailed question. hope you will have a clear understanding and then able to answer my question. Been breaking my head over it for a couple of days but no luck

Comment: would be great if you can help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029238/test-90-and-control-10-split-at-retailer-level-and-also-segment-level-in-s

Answer (score 0):

`percent_rank` is based on `rank` & `count`:

```
select RetailerCode, CID,Segment 
(case when percent_rank() over (partition by segment order by newid()) <= 0.1
             then 'control'
             else 'test'
        end) as group
from Table
Order by RetailerCode
```

And `ntile` is based on `row_number` and `count`:

```
select RetailerCode, CID,Segment 
(case when ntile(10) over (partition by segment order by newid()) = 1
             then 'control'
             else 'test'
        end) as group
from Table
Order by RetailerCode
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you can help me with this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029238/test-90-and-control-10-split-at-retailer-level-and-also-segment-level-in-s) as both the above answers are not quiet yielding the right results. I have explained in detail in the new question. Please help me